# How replace a string of a specific person in a file

Tags: c, string, file

I'm having a bit of problem. I've set the string 'Absent' to all student in a file. However, I want to replace 'Absent' with 'present' when the correct ID assigned to a student is entered. In other words, 'Absent' will only change to 'Present' for a specific person at a time. I'm not sure how to implement this and I'm asking kindly if someone would help. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE::====

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>


typedef struct record {
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  int code;
  char *stat;
} information;


int main (void) {
    int i;
  char ffname[28], flname[28], ans, status[15];

  int fID, j, id_, x;
  FILE *kfile, *ufile;
  x = 0;
  j = 0;
  i = 0;



  char buf[150];
  time_t curtime;
  struct tm* loc_time;
  information array[100];

  printf("          **********Attendance Recording System**********\n");
  printf("                                 MENU                     \n");
//Getting current time of system
  curtime = time (NULL);
// Converting current time to local time
  loc_time = localtime (&curtime);
  strftime (buf,150, "%I:%M %p.\n", loc_time);


//prints error message if file cannot be found within the system

    if ((kfile = fopen("information.txt", "r")) == NULL)    //If the file path is incorrect, an error message is displayed
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening file  (%d: %s)\n",errno, strerror(errno)); //Error message that will be displayed if file path is incorrect

        return;
    }

    //while the file is opened and not at the end, the strings are stored into variables which forms an array of strings
     for (x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
      if (fscanf(kfile, "%s %s %d", ffname, flname, &fID) != 3)  //Reads the contents of the file
      break;
      array[x].fname = strdup(ffname);
      array[x].lname = strdup(flname);
      array[x].code = fID;
    }
   fclose(kfile);

   ufile= fopen("update.txt","w");
        strcpy(status, "Absent");
     fprintf(ufile,"First Name     Last Name     ID     Status     Time Arrived\n");
     for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
     fprintf(ufile,"%-15s%-14s%2d%12s ",(array[i].fname), (array[i].lname), (array[i].code), status);
     fprintf(ufile,"%16s",(buf)); 

}
fclose(ufile);

while(j < x){
printf("Enter you ID: ");
scanf("%d", &id_);

strcpy(status, "Absent");
bool isPresentInFile = false;
for(i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    if(array[x].code == id_)
    {
        printf(" %s %s?", array[x].fname, array[x].lname);
        isPresentInFile  = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(isPresentInFile)
{
    strcpy(status, "present");
}

j++;
}

 fprintf(ufile,"First Name     Last Name     ID     Status     Time Arrived\n");
     for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
     fprintf(ufile,"%-15s%-14s%2d%12s ",(array[i].fname), (array[i].lname), (array[i].code), status);
     fprintf(ufile,"%16s",(buf)); 

}
     fclose(ufile);


getch();
return 0;
}
```

UPDATE #3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>


typedef struct record {
  char *fname;
  char *lname;
  int code;

} information;


int main (void) {
    int i;
  char ffname[28], flname[28], ans, ans1, status[15];

  int fID, j, id_, x;
  FILE *kfile, *ufile;
  x = 0;
  j = 0;
  i = 0;



  char buf[150];
  time_t curtime;
  struct tm* loc_time;
  information array[100];

  printf("          **********Attendance Recording System**********\n");
  printf("                                 MENU                     \n");
//Getting current time of system
  curtime = time (NULL);
// Converting current time to local time
  loc_time = localtime (&curtime);
  strftime (buf,150, "%I:%M %p.\n", loc_time);


//prints error message if file cannot be found within the system

    if ((kfile = fopen("information.txt", "r")) == NULL)    //If the file path is incorrect, an error message is displayed
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error while opening file  (%d: %s)\n",errno, strerror(errno)); //Error message that will be displayed if file path is incorrect

        return;
    }

    //while the file is opened and not at the end, the strings are stored into variables which forms an array of strings
     for (x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
      if (fscanf(kfile, "%s %s %d", ffname, flname, &fID) != 3)  //Reads the contents of the file
      break;
      array[x].fname = strdup(ffname);
      array[x].lname = strdup(flname);
      array[x].code = fID;
    }
   fclose(kfile);



while(j < x){
    Next:
printf("Enter you ID: ");
scanf("%d", &id_);

strcpy(status, "Absent");
bool isPresentInFile = false;
for(i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    if(array[i].code == id_)
    {

        printf("Are you %s %s?", array[i].fname, array[i].lname);
        printf("\n");
        printf("[y/n only]: ");
        scanf(" %c", &ans);


        isPresentInFile  = true;
        break;
    }//end of if statement
}//end of for loop

if(isPresentInFile)
{
    strcpy(status, "present");
}//end of if statement
switch (ans){
    case 'y':
        ufile= fopen("update.txt","w");

     fprintf(ufile,"First Name     Last Name     ID     Status     Time Arrived\n");
     for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
     fprintf(ufile,"%-15s%-14s%2d%12s ",(array[i].fname), (array[i].lname), (array[i].code), status);
     fprintf(ufile,"%16s",(buf)); 


}//end of for loop
fclose(ufile);
printf("Continue?\n");
printf("[y/n]: ");
scanf(" %c", &ans1);

if(ans1 == 'y'){
    break;
}//end of if statements
    else if (ans1 == 'n'){
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }//end of else statement to check if ans1 is equal to 'n'

    case 'n':
        goto Next;
        break;
    default:
        printf("invalid entry. Try again");
}//end of switch case statememt
j++;
}//end of while





getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: By `correct ID` what do you mean ? Is there any definition for correct ID? `should the value be in a particular range ?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I didn't get when exactly do you want to change `status` from `"Absent"` to `"present"`.

But you can use the same `strcpy()` method to overwrite your `status` variable.

```
...
strcpy(status, "Absent");
if(//condition)
{
    strcpy(status, "present");
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

After reading your comment, I understood that you will prompt the user to enter an ID. And if it matches with the ID present in the file, you need to update the `status` to `"present"` and then write to the new file.

I can think of something like this:

```
...
// read from file
.....
int ID;
printf("Enter you ID: ");
scanf("%d", &ID);

strcpy(status, "Absent");
bool isPresentInFile = false;
for(int i=0; i<x; ++i)
{
    if(array[x].code == ID)
    {
        isPresentInFile  = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(isPresentInFile)
{
    strcpy(status, "present");
}

...
// write to file
.....
```

**UPDATE 2:**
After reading the updated question, I notice that you are writing to the file at the end! But overwriting the status variable each time. This way you end up writing either `"Absent"` or `"Present"` for all the entries in the file (Note that it pertains to the last candidate who enters his ID!)

To avoid this, do either of the following:

1. Write to the file as soon as you know the status of a candidate.

   ```
   while(j < x)
   {
   printf("Enter you ID: ");
   scanf("%d", &id_);

   strcpy(status, "Absent");
   bool isPresentInFile = false;
   for(i=0; i<x; i++)
   {
       if(array[x].code == id_)
       {
           printf(" %s %s?", array[x].fname, array[x].lname);
           isPresentInFile  = true;
           break;
       }
   }

   if(isPresentInFile)
   {
       strcpy(status, "present");
   }

   // write to file here

   j++;
   }
   ```
2. Also have a field called `status` in the structure `information`.
   By default, keep it `"Absent"` for all the candidates.
   Then make it `"Present"` only for those who enter their IDs. Finally, write it to the file.

Comment: i want to change it after the student enter their id and it matches with their id in the file. So by the snippet that you have just sent, will it only overwrite 'Absent' for that particular student? or will it overwrite every 'Absent' within the file?

Comment: @SantoshA By correct ID I mean, the program prompts the user to enter their ID and it will search a file for the same ID. If it matches any in the file, it will change 'Absent' to 'Present'

Comment: @Kkkkkkkkkkkk : Make sure to add that to the question to get a more specific answer.

Comment: @Kkkkkkkkkkkk From what you have done I don't see any `scanf` to request user for their ID.

Comment: That's my bad. The scanf is within the code though. Can I send an email for you to view what i have?

Comment: @GargAnkit Thanks for your reply, I'm going to try this now and get back to you

Comment: @GargAnkit I'm having sime issues. Im not able to get the present printed out to the file. Can i send an email with it and you take a look at it?

Comment: @Kkkkkkkkkkkk How about posting your complete code?

Comment: @GargAnkit I wanted you to see the actual file as well and how it works.

Comment: Post everything here: code, input file,  corresponding output file. I'll take a look :)

Comment: @GargAnkit I have done what you've posted, it has changed the 'Absent' to 'Present'. However, it still changes every 'Absent' in the file to 'Present'

Comment: Which method did you try - first or second?

Comment: I tried #1 first. I'm not sure how to set status to default as 'Absent' since it would be of an array.

Comment: Why don't you try the second approach? That is more understandable.

Comment: Im not sure about what u mean by making it "Present" for those who enter thier ID. Can you give an example please

Comment: I posted an updated version of my code above so you can see what I;ve done